# What is the correct way to write data to a file using worker thread in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am developing an application in Qt, which is UI intensive. It is UI intensive because, my application displays logs,which come at a very high speed and UI has to reflect that.

Now after the number of logs exceed a certain amount, My previous logs will start to get deleted, because my UI window has a limit(100000 logs, to keep app fast).

So in order to save the old logs , I want to write the old logs to a file, before they get deleted.

**Problem**

If I write the file in main thread,my UI hangs(becomes very slow). So I decided to write file in a worker thread. This is what I did this:

I made my own class `WorkerThread` that inherits class `QThread` and inside that class `run()` method, I write the data to a file.

The data that I want to write is stored in threads member variables itself:

So my code is:

**Some other class function**
.
.
.
.

```
WorkerThread *workerThread = new WorkerThread();
connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(resultReady()), workerThread, SLOT(quit()));
workerThread->attribute1 = dataToWrite1;
workerThread->attribute2 = dataToWrite2;
workerThread->start();
```

**WorkerThread class**

```
class WorkerThread : public QThread
{
Q_OBJECT

public:

  QString attribute1;
  QString attribute2;  

protected:
    void run() {    
            // DELIMITER IS ..:  //                 

            QFile myFile("C:/shiftedlines/myFile.txt");
            if(myFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Append))
            {    
                QTextStream stream(&myFile);
                stream<< attribute1<<"..:";
                stream<< attribute2<<"\n";   
            }
        emit resultReady();
    }
signals:
    void resultReady();
};
```

But after **writing about 500 lines, my application crashes**. How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Why the close votes? Please explain.

Comment: Generally you do not need to inherit `QThread`, you can write a generic class which inherits `QObject`, create a `QThread` and use `moveToThread` on your object. You can then use a signal from your class to end the thread and destroy anything. In my experience this works pretty good.

Comment: @Bowdzone Can you please paste a minimal , examplry code.

Comment: All the examples you need are in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details).  On which line does your code crash under a debugger and what's the call stack?

Comment: Start by reading [this article](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) on how to use `QThread`, without inheriting and follow that method. Then I suggest using [QSaveFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsavefile.html) in preference to QFile.

Answer (score 0):

This does not address the issue you are having but since you asked this in the comments, this is how I implemented such tasks in the past.

**worker class**

```
class worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        worker();

    public slots:
        void start();

    signals:
        void finished();
};
```

**main**

```
worker* cur_worker = new worker();

// move to its own thread
QThread* worker_thread = new QThread(this);
cur_worker->moveToThread(worker_thread);
QObject::connect(worker_thread, SIGNAL(started()), cur_worker, SLOT(start()));
QObject::connect(cur_worker, SIGNAL(finished()), worker_thread, SLOT(quit()));
QObject::connect(worker_thread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker_thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

// start
worker_thread->start();
```

This example does not handle the destruction of the worker object, which in your case you probably want to do immediately.

Comment: When your answer to a question starts with, *"This does not address the issue you are having"*, it is clear that there is a problem with your answer.

Comment: @Cody Gray It addresses what OP asked in the comments, although his solution should work as well this might be an XY problem

Answer (score 0):

Writing to a file should be quite fast as long as it's done correctly.

**What is slow is not writing to the file, but opening it.**

Make sure you don't open / close the file each time you receive a log, but open the file in write only and append mode, **and keep it open** while your application is running and writing log.

Usually you can write in recent SSD drive at a speed around 700MB/s of data, so I doubt that you would have any noticeable impact on the UI.

---

If you really want to go for thread (which IMO is probably overkill) don't forget that to be thread safe, you have to communicate with your thread using signals / slots.

From your code, it seems you start a new thread for each log write, which each tries to open the file. Your file can be written only by one thread at a time and this will be blocked by the system, so above 1 thread for writing into a file, it is useless to have more.

Probably your threads hangs into trying to open the file which is already accessed by some other, and end up with hundreds of hanging threads which ends up in a memory overflow if you have them in the stack.

The roule of Open your file once and write as long as you have something to write also applies in the thread.